# How to check if multiple documents exist

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there such a query that gets multiple fields, and returns which of these exists in the collection?
For example, if the collection has only:

```
{id : 1}
{id : 2}
```

And I want to know which of `[{id : 1} , {id : 3}]` exists in it, then the result will be something like `[{id : 1}]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are looking for the [$in-operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).

```
db.collection.find({ id: { $in: [ 1, 3 ] } });
```

This will get you any documents where the id-field (different from the special `_id` field) is 1 or 3. When you only want the values of the id field and not the whole documents:

```
db.collection.find({ id: { $in: [ 1, 3 ] } }, { _id: false, id:true });
```

Comment: @Philipp by the way, I think there is a missing bracket in 
`db.collection.find({ id: { $in: { [ 1, 3 ] } }, { _id: false, id:true });`
also

Comment: @eMAD No, actually it's one bracket too many :) But thanks for calling my attention.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check provided `key with value` is present or not in collection, you can simply check by matching values and combining conditions using `$or` operator.

**By considering `id` is different than `_id` in mongo.**

You can use [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) to get expected output and query will be as following.

```
db.collection.find({$or:[{"id":1},{"id":3}]},{"_id":0,"id":1})
```

If you want to match `_id` then use following query:

```
db.collection.find({$or:[{"_id":ObjectId("557fda78d077e6851e5bf0d3")},{"_id":ObjectId("557fda78d077e6851e5bf0d5")}]}
```

Comment: $or should only be used when you have conditions on multiple different fields. When you have a list of possible values for one field, you should use $in.